# Keras training/testing results vary greatly after multiple runs

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am using Keras with TensorFlow backend. The dataset I am working with is sequence data with a Y value that is continuous between 0 and 1. The dataset is split into training with size 1900 and a testing with size 400. I am using the VGG19 architecture that I created from scratch in Keras. I am using an epoch of 30.

My question is, if I run this architecture multiple times, I get very different results. My results can be between 0.15 and 0.5 RMSE. Is this normal for this type of data? Is it because I am not running enough epochs? The loss from the network seems to stabilize around 0.024 at the end of the run. Any ideas?

Comment: Its normal for results to vary across runs due to random initialization, but whatever that's normal for your data, its a judgment call. You could get more stability if you train for more epochs (like 50).

Comment: Another way to get some reproducibility is to set your random seed.